# Costa ou Costas?

Tags: número-gramatical

Qual é o correto `Costa` ou `Costas`? Por exemplo,

> Eu bati as costas

ou

> Eu bati a costa

Comment: Pois é sempre fico com essa duvida, pois costas me parece plural, sendo que só temos 1.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert estranhamente falamos "minhas costas" e não "minha costas", presumo que "costas", eu acho que tem haver com as costelas, mas ainda não achei explicação para a origem :/

Comment: Pois é a fonética fica estranha, creio que por causa disse temos costume de disser "minhas costas". Essa analise das costelas parece coerente :D

Comment: E existe  a costa Litoral e a costa no Corpo!

Comment: @ClMend e é no plural ou não do corpo? No corpo temos duas "costas"? ou uma "costas" (ou costa)? Na etimologia então costas com s, plural, seria apenas um neologismo, ou realmente se refere a tag que eu apliquei na pergunta, e que é o que eu perguntei [tag:número-gramatical]? Deu pra entender agora?

Answer (score 5):

## Costas

Parte do corpo.

## Costa

Parte litorânea de uma localização geográfica, como um país ou um continente.